# How to avoid multiple Nokogiri requests inside a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a gem.
Here is the homepage of it: 
https://github.com/scaryguy/vakit

If you check out the source code, you can see that I'm parsing an external HTML page to filter some data from it.

The issue is, eventhough I fetch all data I want with one request, each time I call `Vakit.sabah` or `Vakit.oglen` a new request is done.

```
require "vakit/version"
require 'vakit/connect'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

module Vakit

  def self.today
    Vakit::Connect.shaber
  end

  def self.imsak
    Vakit::Connect.shaber[:imsak]
  end

  def self.sabah
    Vakit::Connect.shaber[:sabah]
  end

  def self.oglen
    Vakit::Connect.shaber[:oglen]
  end

  def self.ikindi
    Vakit::Connect.shaber[:ikindi]
  end

  def self.aksam
    Vakit::Connect.shaber[:aksam]
  end

  def self.yatsi
    Vakit::Connect.shaber[:yatsi]
  end

end
```

I don't think that it's an efficient way.

I should be able to access attributes of my hash without new request, shouldn't I?

```
module Vakit
class Connect
    def initialize(opt={})
        @path = opt[:path]
    end

    def self.shaber
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.samanyoluhaber.com/'))
        x = doc.css('#hnmzT')

        times = []
        x.each do |vakit|
            data = vakit.children.first.children.last.content
            data_add = data.slice(0..data.length-2)
            times.push(data_add)
        end
        times
        vakit = {

            imsak: times[0],
            sabah: times[1],
            oglen: times[2],
            ikindi: times[3],
            aksam: times[4],
            yatsi: times[5]


        }

    end

end
end
```

I need some enlightment.

Comment: Don't ask us to chase down your code to help you. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line 
`doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.samanyoluhaber.com/'))` is what's making the requested call several times.

I tested this with your gem and this seems to work.

```
if @doc.nil?
  @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.samanyoluhaber.com/'))
end
```

In addition in vakit.rb change

`require 'Nokogiri' to require 'nokogiri'` (simple n)

Comment: Thank you very much. Keyword is using power of instance variables!

Comment: Often this kind of simple lazy eval/caching is written `@doc ||= ...` without the `if` block in Ruby, although nothing wrong with answer as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use `shaber` you explicitly `open` and reparse the content. You're not making an attempt to locally store the content or parsed DOM and check to see if you already have it.

Instead of `doc =` use `@@doc ||=` and change the occurrences of `doc` to `@@doc`.

The `||=` operator will only assign when `@@doc` is empty. Once it's assigned to a non-nil or non-false value it won't trigger again so it's a poor-mans "memoize".

Because you are using a class-method I recommended using a class variable. `@@doc` could be an instance variable `@doc` instead if you have multiple instances of the class that are looking at different pages. As is, that won't make a difference because you've hard-coded only one page, but for future code-growth it might be useful.

---

The code you've written to access the page isn't very idiomatic Ruby. I'd write it more like the following, which doesn't work because the URL isn't returning a page that has enough time values:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

module Vakit

  URL = 'http://www.samanyoluhaber.com/'

  class Connect
    def initialize(opt={})
      @path = opt[:path]
      @url = opt[:url] || URL
    end

    def shaber(url=nil)
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url || @url))
      doc.at_css('#hnmzT').to_html # => "<li id=\"hnmzT\" name=\"imsak\"><a id=\"at\"><span>\u0130msak:</span>4:22\u00A0</a></li>"

      x = doc.at_css('li#hnmzT a')
      x.to_html # => "<a id=\"at\"><span>\u0130msak:</span>4:22\u00A0</a>"

      times = x.text.scan(/\d+:\d+/)

      Hash[[:imsak, :sabah, :oglen, :ikindi, :aksam, :yatsi].zip(times)]
    end

  end
end

connection = Vakit::Connect.new
connection.shaber # => {:imsak=>"4:22", :sabah=>nil, :oglen=>nil, :ikindi=>nil, :aksam=>nil, :yatsi=>nil}
```

`Connect` isn't a good name for a class. A class is an object, a thing. `Connect` is a verb, something that occurs, or happens, to a thing. `connect` would be a good name for a method.

Answer (score 0):

I will make the following suggestions:

1. `Vakit::Connect` should be an instance method inside a class. so it can be instantiated & saved in memory. this way each request will be different instances of the same object. if class doesn't exist. Do create it.
2. use [`memorization`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorization) to cache costly operations.
3. If the operation takes long time, say greater than 3sec. convert it into a background job & use workers to process them.however, since you are authoring a gem. I think this responsibility should be delagated to developers using the gem.

so I would do it something like this:
the connect class:

```
module Vakit
class Connect
attr_accessor :path, :doc
def initialize(opt={}, url)
  @path = opt[:path]
  @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
end

def shaber
 x = @doc.css('#hnmzT')
  #no changes here
end
end
```

the Vakit module

```
module Vakit
 class Main #name it something more meaningful   
  def initialize(opt={})
   @connected = Connect.new(opt[:path], 'http://www.samanyoluhaber.com/')
  end
  def today
   @connected.shaber
  end

  def imsak
   today[:imsak]
  end

  def sabah
   today[:sabah]
  end

  def oglen
   today[:oglen]
  end

  def ikindi
   today[:ikindi]
  end

  def aksam
   today[:aksam]
  end

  def yatsi
   today[:yatsi]
  end

end
```

then in code, you can use it like this:

```
@v = Vakit::Main.new
@v.aksam
```

This may not be 100% perfect because I really don't understand the purpose of your code, O understand what its doing but not why. But this will not make new request everytime you access your hash.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer But how to alias to the module name with your solution?

Comment: you can just assign `Valkit` to another constant. `V = Vakit; @v = V::Main.new`. Is this what you asking?

Comment: I mean, while using gem users should be able to call like `Vakit.sabah`. In your solution it should be `Vakit::Main.sabah` . How to create an alias for that?

Comment: "class Main #name it something more meaningful "? Meaningful? Ruby isn't Java or C++. "Main" isn't meaningful at all. Name a class after the object it represents.